# Continuous surjections onto $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I have two questions about continuous functions:

1. Suppose $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $X$ has same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. Can we find a continuous function from $X$ onto $\mathbb{R}$?
2. Suppose $X \cup Y = \mathbb{R}$. Can we find a continuous function from one of $X, Y$ onto $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The answer to (1) is no.  For example, $X = [0,1]$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, but there is no continuous surjection $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ since $[0,1]$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}$ is not.

Comment: Without restriction on $X \cup Y = \mathbb{R}$ you can do $X=[0,1]$ and the answer is clealrly yes

Comment: @LuisGomezSanchez: but what if $X = \mathbb{Q}$ in question 2?

Comment: Note that $X=\mathbb{Q}$ is *not* a counterexample to question (2).  The irrational numbers are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ under the product topology (i.e. [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_%28set_theory%29)), and it's not hard to define a continuous surjection $\mathbb{N}^\omega \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I've added the "general topology" and "descriptive set theory" tags.

Comment: @RobArthan: Exactly, why have not limited, for example, to set $X=\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $X \cup Y = \mathbb{R}$ in whose case the question is clearly more difficult?

Comment: @JimBelk: thanks. What you pointed out is exactly what I was expecting, implying that a counterexample must have $X$ and $Y$ both uncountable.

Answer (score 19):

The answer to (2) is affirmative. Let $f:R \to R^2$ be a continuous surjection. Let $\pi_x, \pi_y: R^2 \to R$ be projections onto $x, y$ axes. Now notice that if $X \cup Y = R$, then either $(\pi_x \circ f)[X] = R$ or $(\pi_y \circ f)[Y] = R$. Hence one of $X, Y$ can be continuously mapped onto $R$.

Comment: Why is it that $\mathbb R^2 = A\cup B\implies \pi_x(A)=\mathbb R\vee\pi_y(B)=\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli If $\pi_x(A) \ne \mathbb{R}$, there must be a whole vertical line contained in $B$.

Comment: @JimBelk Thank you kindly.

Comment: This is really a fantastic solution!  I had expected this question to be much more difficult.

Comment: One reason this solution is amazing is that the resulting statement is much stronger than what was asked for.  Dorothy has shown that there exist two continuous surjections $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that, for any $X$ and $Y$ with $X\cup Y = \mathbb{R}$, either $f(X) = \mathbb{R}$ or $g(Y) = \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

To make question (1) more interesting replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $[0, 1]$ so that the question becomes: Can we map every continuum size set of reals onto $[0, 1]$? Under CH, the answer is no by a simple diagonalization (or just note that a Lusin/Sierpinski set is a counterexample). One the other hand, Arnold Miller has proved ([see here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/map.pdf)) that in the iterated Sacks model this is true. He also mentions an observation of J. Isbell: Whenever a perfect set of reals is partitioned into countably many sets, one of these sets can be continuously mapped onto $[0, 1]$.